# sfml dosen't want to link in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-studio-2019

I want to make a new project that uses sfml .
I added it in the additional include and additional library like normal, in the linker input i added `sfml-graphics-d.lib` but it can't open it, the library is in drive D and visual studio dosen't seem to complain in the editor, how can i resolve this?

[image: Include Directory]
[image: Additional Dependencies]
[image: Library directory]

The only code is just that:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(320, 480)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your compile output? What is the full commandline (you can enable verbose linking in the linker menu)

Comment: Maybe the `.lib` files are 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you link dynamically, you need to include the .dll from the sfml bin folder in your project, be sure to copy the right ones, there are 2 types, 1 for debug 1 for release. Copy them into your project debug/release folder